# How to weave lines of two different jq statements together

Tags: json, unix, jq

I have the following jq statement:

```
cat main.json | jq .hits.hits[] | jq -c '{"index":{"_index": ._index, "_type": ._type, "_id": ._id}}'
```

which gives me something like:

```
{"index":{"_index":"main","_type":"default","_id":"64"}}
{"index":{"_index":"main","_type":"default","_id":"65"}}
```

And another jq statement:

```
cat main.json | jq .hits.hits[] | jq -c '._source'
```

which gives me something like:

```
{"mainContentOfPage":"hidden","informationType":"Product","url":"hidden","_id":"64"}
{"mainContentOfPage":"hidden","informationType":"Product","url":"hidden","_id":"65"}
```

Now I want to combine these statements so that I get their results on consecutive rows, like this:

```
{"index":{"_index":"main","_type":"default","_id":"64"}}
{"mainContentOfPage":"hidden","informationType":"Product","url":"hidden","_id":"64"}  
{"index":{"_index":"main","_type":"default","_id":"65"}}
{"mainContentOfPage":"hidden","informationType":"Product","url":"hidden","_id":"65"}
```

which will allow me to index these using [Elasticsearch's Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/docs-bulk.html).

How can I combine the two statements to give me the result I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comma (also, I've simplified the key-value selectors to use the shorthand syntax):

```
jq -c '.hits.hits[] | { index: { _index, _type, _id } }, ._source' main.json
```